# Plural des Worts „Magma” (in der Algebra)

Tags: word-usage, mathematics

In der Algebra ist ein [*Magma*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(Mathematik)) eine algebraische Struktur etc., und laut [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Magma) ist *Magmen* der Plural von *Magma*. Allerdings lese ich [hier](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-0348-5752-9#page-1) (S. 33-40) *Magmas* und, wenn ich richtig verstanden habe, dass *Magmas* der Plural von *Magma* im Text von Springer ist, frage ich mich, wer Recht hat, Duden oder Springer? Außerdem kann ich weder das Wort *Magmen* noch das Wort *Magmas*, außer dem Text von Springer, in keinen anderen Algebrabücher finden.

Comment: (1) der Duden bezieht sich auf das geschmolzene Gestein, dessen Plural ist nicht notwendigerweise identisch. (2) Das Buch ist von 1975, als der Begriff noch nicht sonderlich alt war (womöglich ist *Gruppoid* gebräuchlicher), damals war er sicherlich noch weniger eingedeutscht. 
*Magmas* und *Magmen* sind ansonsten nur unterschiedliche Eindeutschungsstufen, wirklich falsch ist wohl keine.

Comment: Wikipedia benutzt _Magmen_: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_%28Mathematik%29

Comment: @chirlu, oh! du hast Recht, ich habe das nicht gemerkt...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Der Begriff *Magma* wurde von französischen Mathematikern eingeführt und im Französischen wäre der Plural *Magmas*. Vielleicht wurde das deshalb in deiner Quelle so gemacht. Sehe aber keinen Grund, warum man nicht den deutschen Plural *Magmen* verwenden sollte.

[Hier](https://books.google.de/books?id=QmCiBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA2&dq=magmen%20algebra&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFgP7dobDNAhWmBcAKHXjlBYEQ6AEIHzAA#v=onepage&q=magmen%20algebra&f=false) ein deutsches Algebrabuch, in dem *Magma* mit Plural *Magmen* verwendet wird. Ich konnte allerdings auf die schnelle kein weiteres Magma in einem deutschen Buch finden.

Answer (score 2):

*Magmen* sollte richtig sein, da sich das Wort ja gut eindeutschen läßt. In einer Rezension des oben angegebenen Buches von Gerritzen wird auch Magmen verwendet. Zumindest ist es ein Beleg mehr.

[image: Rezension in *Monatshefte für Mathematik*]